# Using Koa as Nuxt server middleware

Tags: nuxt.js, koa

I am trying to use Koa as server middleware for nuxt. When I make a request to localhost:3000/api/users I get no response, route not found. What is wrong with my code?

**nuxt.config.js**

```
serverMiddleware: [
    // API middleware
    '~/api/index.js'
    ]
```

**index.js**

```
const Koa = require('koa')
const Api = require('koa-router')
const users = require('./routes/users')

const koa = new Koa()
const api = new Api()

api.use('/users', users.routes())

koa.use(api.routes())
koa.use(api.allowedMethods())

// Export the server middleware
module.exports = {
  path: '/api',
  handler: koa
}
```

**users.js**

```
const Router = require('koa-router')

const router = new Router()

router.get('/users', ctx => {
  ctx.body = 'Hello World'
})

module.exports = router
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use [`app.callback()`](https://github.com/koajs/koa/blob/master/docs/api/index.md#appcallback) instead of just `app` as handler:

```
import Koa from 'koa'
const app = new Koa()

app.use(ctx => {
  ctx.body = 'Hello World'
})

app.listen()

export default {
  path: '/example',
  handler: app.callback()
}
```